# How to stop the JsonBuilder from arranging field order

Tags: java, json, groovy

Does anyone know how to stop the JsonBuilder method from messing w/ the field order. I have a class object that I pass into the JsonBuilder method and it's arranging my fields. How can I stop this behavior?

```
class JsonObj {
     String firstName = "";
     String middleName = "";
     String lastName = "";
 }

JsonObj jc = new JsonObj();
println new JsonBuilder(jc).toPrettyString();
```

Results:

```
{
    "firstName": "",
    "lastName": "",
    "middleName": ""
}
```

I need this format as per my class object:

```
{
    "firstName": "",
    "middleName": "",
    "lastName": ""
}
```

Comment: What package are you using? groovy? please indicate the package.

Comment: I'm using groovy 2.4.8. This example I provided above is simplified. My main class object has over 25 fields. I can have the builder arranging my fields. It seems like there should be a way to stop this behavior. Btw, I'm stuck using 2.4.8 =) Tnx for helping.

Comment: read this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972795/groovy-jsonbuilder-object-properties-being-serialized-in-random-order

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Groovy JsonBuilder: object properties being serialized in random order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972795/groovy-jsonbuilder-object-properties-being-serialized-in-random-order)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use JsonOutput class instead of JsonBuilder

```
JsonObj jc = new JsonObj()
def js_json = JsonOutput.toJson(jc)
println JsonOutput.prettyPrint(js_json)
```